# QTimer never fires timeout when singleShot is True

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I am attempting to use a `QTimer` to append buffered lines to my subclass of `QStandatdItemModel`.
Note that in my code below I have also tried using `QTimer.singleShot(self.refresh, self.__dump_buffer)` instead of instantiating `QTimer`, and neither style seems to work, static member or instantiated class methods. I also tried moving the `QTimer` to the main thread, this did not help. No matter what I try, the slot connected to `QTimer.timeout` never seems to be fired, no matter what I try. I have verified this by the fact that `Dump buffer` is never printed to the console.

```
class ProgressLogItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, limit=1000, refresh=20):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.limit = limit
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.buffer = list()

        # self.timer.moveToThread(QApplication.instance().thread())
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.setInterval(refresh)  # The default is 20ms, being 50Hz

        # Every time the single-shot timer runs out after 'refresh' milliseconds, dump the buffer
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.__dump_buffer)

    @helpers.make_slot()
    def __dump_buffer(self):
        print("Dump buffer")
        self.insertRows(self.rowCount(), len(self.buffer))

        for offset, item in enumerate(self.buffer):
            self.setData(self.index(self.rowCount() - len(self.buffer) + offset, 0), item)

        self.buffer.clear()  # Reset the buffer
        # Not sure if the 'stop()' this is necessary but it is here
        # to ensure that 'isActive()' returns 'False'
        self.timer.stop()

    def __apply_limit(self):
        if self.rowCount() > self.limit:
            # Remove rows from the beginning, count being the number of rows over the limit
            self.removeRows(0, self.rowCount() - self.limit)

    def insertRows(self, row, count, _=None):
        super().insertRows(row, count)

        self.__apply_limit()

    def appendRow(self, item):
        # Append the QStandardItem to the internal list to be popped into the model on the next timeout
        self.buffer.append(item)

        # If the timer is not currently running (this method has not been called
        # before less than 'refresh' milliseconds ago), start the next single-shot to dump the buffer
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            print("Timer started")
            self.timer.start()  # Start the next single-shot


class ExampleProgressLogDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.progress_log_list_view = QListView(self)
        self.progress_log_item_model = ProgressLogItemModel(self.progress_log_list_view)

        self.progress_log_list_view.setModel(self.progress_log_item_model)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.progress_log_list_view)

    def log(self, text):
        self.progress_log_item_model.appendRow(QStandardItem(text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from threading import Thread
    from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication()
    dialog = ExampleProgressLogDialog()

    def __add_log_lines():
        for line in range(10000):
            dialog.log(f"Log line: {line}")

    add_log_lines_thread = Thread(target=__add_log_lines(), daemon=True)
    add_log_lines_thread.start()

    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In reality the subclass'ed `QDialog` would be instantiated from an instance of `QMainWindow` when feedback should be given to the user. The `QTimer` would be started from any potential thread that wants to call the `log` method.

Comment: How are you using `appendRow()`? Can you extend your code by providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, you're saying "I also tried moving the QTimer to the main thread": do you mean that you put the model to a separate thread? If that's so, why?

Comment: @musicamante Have done so. I'm not sure if the minimal example really reflects the actual usage of the (large) class that utilizes `ProgressLogItemModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `helpers.make_slot` does, so I just commented it, and the `__dump_buffer` is correctly called.

There is one big problem, though: with QStandardItemModel it's not enough to insert rows, you also have to set QStandardItems for those indexes using `setItem()` (and not `setData()`).

Change that cycle to this:

```
        for offset, item in enumerate(self.buffer):
            self.setItem(self.rowCount() - len(self.buffer) + offset, 0, item)
```

Note that access to Qt objects directly from a python thread is discouraged. While, in this case, it's not a big issue (since QStandardItems are not QObjects, but QStandardItemModel *is*), it's usually better to create QThread subclasses and use signals/slots to interact with Qt objects that are in the main thread.

Comment: `helpers.make_slot` does exactly what the name of the decorator says it does, it wraps the function with a Qt slot. It also does some other stuff to make sure the slot is named properly for the Qt bindings being used, since `qtpy` does not. Also, thank you for the solution, and making the changes to use a signal did fix the issue.

Comment: The `@pyqtSlot` decorator does exactly what you are describing; in any case, we don't know exactly what your decorator does, and, theoretically, it could also be a reason for your issue: for future reference, you either include the code related to it, or you don't use it in the example.

Comment: @musicamanate My decorator is simply a wrapper around both PyQt and PySide2 slot functions. That is all.